# lodash: Filtering object in object with pickBy

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to use `"lodash": "^4.17.10"` to filter an object.

See below my minimum viable example:

```js
const obj = {
    "2": {
        "title": "GeForce GTX 1070 SC GAMING ACX 3.0 Black Edition",
        "category": [{
            "term_id": 34,
            "name": "Graphic Card",
            "slug": "graphic-card",
            "term_group": 0,
        }],
        "currency": "$",
        "price": "547.85",
        "watt": "0",
    },
    "3": {
        "title": "GeForce White Edition",
        "category": [{
            "term_id": 32,
            "name": "other-card",
            "slug": "other-card",
            "term_group": 0,
        }],
        "currency": "$",
        "price": "600.85",
        "watt": "0",
    }
}

let allGpuParts = _.pickBy(obj, (value, key) => {
    return _.startsWith(key.category, "graphic-card")
})

console.log("allGpuParts")
console.log(allGpuParts)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

As you can currently there is no result returned. I would like to get back only the object `"2":`, which has the slug `"slug": "graphic-card"`.

Any suggestions how to filter with lodash?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `_.filter` and `_.isMatch` to find the key value pair you're looking for `_.some` just means if any match `return true`.

```js
const obj = {
    "2": {
        "title": "GeForce GTX 1070 SC GAMING ACX 3.0 Black Edition",
        "category": [{
            "term_id": 34,
            "name": "Graphic Card",
            "slug": "graphic-card",
            "term_group": 0,
        }],
        "currency": "$",
        "price": "547.85",
        "watt": "0",
    },
    "3": {
        "title": "GeForce White Edition",
        "category": [{
            "term_id": 32,
            "name": "other-card",
            "slug": "other-card",
            "term_group": 0,
        }],
        "currency": "$",
        "price": "600.85",
        "watt": "0",
    }
}

const isGPU = o => _.isMatch(o, {slug: "graphic-card"});
const allGpuParts = _.filter(obj, ({category}) => category.some(isGPU));

console.log("allGpuParts")
console.log(allGpuParts)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Please let me know if I've misunderstood or if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

- *category* is an *Array of Objects*, so you need to iterate it in some way, e.g. by using [*Array.prototype.some*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to find if there is any item which meets a condition
- You need to check against *slug* itself rather than testing a string-vs-object category

I've kept a *startsWith* test although your current example would also work with an exact match

```
const graphicCategory = cat => cat.slug.startsWith('graphic-card'); // true or false test

_.pickBy(
    obj, // your object
    value => value.category.some(graphicCategory) // pick if some category has graphic-card
); // {2: { ... }}
```